# npm install gives 'npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND' error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

As the title suggests, I am having an issue with `npm install`. Today on my development site I noticed that one of my packages , reactjs-popup, was missing with the `Module not found: Can't resolve 'reactjs-popup' in 'pathway-to-file'` error. As a result, I tried to install that module again but received this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/reactjs-popup failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com proxy.company.com:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I've tried tinkering with the proxy using commands such as:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

but have not had any luck. Here is my error-log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'reactjs-popup' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose npm-session 163a96058a70d601
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for reactjs-popup@^1.5.0 request to http://registry.npmjs.org/reactjs-popup failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com proxy.company.com:8080
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1759ms
10 verbose type system
11 verbose stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/reactjs-popup failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com proxy.company.com:8080
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
11 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
11 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
11 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\jschriem\Desktop\jsdash\frontend
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "reactjs-popup"
15 verbose node v10.16.0
16 verbose npm  v6.9.0
17 error code ENOTFOUND
18 error errno ENOTFOUND
19 error network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/reactjs-popup failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com proxy.company.com:8080
20 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
20 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
20 error network
20 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
20 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck for quite some time and other resources haven't proved too helpful. Thank you!

Comment: This is more of an issue of your corportate proxy from the looks of it

Comment: I think so as well, however, I am still looking for a solution if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to delete that proxy. Try using `delete npmrc` and then `install react-scripts`.

Comment: please can you explain a bit further, have similar issues doing npm install and npm install --save firebase for a vue project